# Accessing Ractive components from their parent

Tags: ractivejs

I find myself in a situation where I would like to access the instances created from a Ractive component from the parent Ractive.
E.g.

```
var myComponent = Ractive.extend(
    {
        uselessFunction: function()
        {
            alert('Hello ' + this.data.who);
        }
    }
);

var myRactive = new Ractive(
    {
        el: 'body',
        components:
        {
            mycomponent: myComponent
        },
        template: '{{#people}}<rv-mycomponent who="{{.}}"/>{{/people}}',
        data:
        {
            people:
            [
                'Mike',
                'Charly',
                'April'
            ]
        }
    }
);
```

Running that I will get 3 instances of myComponent. Now what I'd like to have would be some way to call the uselessFunction on any component instance from within a method of myRactive (or even better on all instances).

There are of course many possible workarounds (like using observers in the components and then changing some shared property) to achieve this but I was hoping for some built in interface of sorts. Alas, as much as I sift through the myRactive Object, I can't seem to find a reference to the component instances. Though I suspect there to be one, seeing as a teardown() of myComponent also calls teardown() on each component.

Answer (score 2):

**Update: this answer is very old. The correct way to access child components is with `ractive.findComponent(name)` or `ractive.findAllComponents(name)`**

---

There isn't a *good* way to do this, but it is possible:

```js
people = [];

Ractive.components.person = Ractive.extend({
  init: function () {
    people.push( this );
  },
  uselessFunction: function () {
    alert( 'Hello ' + this.get('who') );
  }
};

ractive = new Ractive({
  el: 'body',
  template: '{{#people}}<person who="{{.}}"/>{{/people}}',
  data: { people: [ 'Mike', 'Charly', 'April' ] }
};

// later...
people[0].uselessFunction(); // alerts 'Hello Mike'
```

(n.b. this code won't work with the current release, it assumes you're on [0.3.8](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/tree/0.3.8/build), which ditches `rv-` and allows you to register components globally on `Ractive.components`.)

As I say it's fairly inelegant. Have been trying to figure out the best way to address this. One approach I'm investigating would be to allow `ractive.find()` and `ractive.findAll()` - which are similar to `ractive.el.querySelector()`/`ractive.el.querySelectorAll()` - to find components (e.g. `ractive.findAll('people')`) as well as DOM nodes. Am open to any suggestions in the meantime!

Comment: The global namespace is not an option as I'm working with an AMD setup. But I am using a rather similar workaround at the moment, where I pass an object down to the components that gets the instances injected. Finding workarounds isn't my problem though ;).

Wouldn't it be possible to simply have a property in the ractive object (like 'subcomponents' or whatever) that holds references to the component instances?

Comment: I see that the component instance holds a reference to the "parent" in .component.parentFragment.root, so theoretically I could use that to inject a reference to my component into the parent. Alas, the .component property is not yet available when any of the callback functions (beforeInit, complete, init) are called.

Comment: Seems like every component should know about its children. I can't think of one frameowrk I've used that *didn't*, at least not on the desktop.

Comment: @skeptic35 As of the latest dev version (0.3.9-pre) components have a `this._parent` reference which is used internally. It has a leading underscore because I don't think it's good practice for a component to be able to muck about with its parent (makes it less reusable etc), so it's not a 'proper' part of the API - but equally I didn't see any value in hiding it from users of the library.

Comment: @Joel - Yep, you reminded me this needs a GitHub issue. [Voila!](https://github.com/RactiveJS/Ractive/issues/343) Thanks for the prompt

Comment: @RichHarris Maybe update this answer to the comment from the issue mentioned in the issue mentioned above? https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/1556#issuecomment-66140561

Comment: @mikemaccana good spot, I've updated the answer to 'use `ractive.findComponent`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like [.findComponent()](http://docs.ractivejs.org/0.8/ractive-findcomponent) is now this is done now:

```
ractiveInstance.findComponent( name )
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is similar solution I use:

```
Ractive.defaults.isolated=true;
componentsHash = {};  // GLOBAL
Ractive.defaults.oninit=function(){
    if (this.get('ref'))
        componentsHash[this.get('ref')]=this;
};
Ractive.defaults.onteardown=function(){
    if (this.get('ref') && componentsHash[this.get('ref')])
        delete(componentsHash[this.get('ref')]);
};
```

Object "componentsHash" contains reference to all created components.

Usage:

```
<some-component ref="Mike1"/>
<some-component ref="Mike2"/>
```

Then you can find Mike1 component instance by using:

```
componentsHash['Mike1']
```